# Including a JS source with an admin page

Tags: plugin-development, admin

The administration part for my plugin is divided into several pages and for some pages I would like to enqueue a JS source which would add jQuery functionality to various elements.

Right now this is my approach:

```
function admin_register_init() {

 if ($_GET['page'] == 'worldexplorer_admin_location_hub')
  wp_enqueue_script('worldexplorer_admin_hub', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/worldexplorer/admin/admin_hub.js');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_register_init');
```

However, this requires me to check the page index of the $_GET array. Is there another way to achieve what I wish to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a hook `admin_print_scripts-{$page}` which might fit.

See this [Load scripts only on plugin pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_scripts_only_on_plugin_pages)